# Ingesting data into MongoDB causes "stack level too deep"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a bunch of records stored in a mongodb collection (StudentRecord). These need to be broken out into a Collection of type Student with the Embedded Document StudentGrade. For some reason, the rake task I'm using to do this ingestion keeps hitting a "stack level too deep". I can't detect any recursive calls and I'm using bundle exec to execute it (ruby 1.9.2-p320).

```
task :parse_student_records => :environment do
  StudentRecord.all.each{|student_record|
    student = Student.create({:name => student_record.name})
    student.grades « Grade.create({:score => student_record.grade_score)
    student.save!
  }
end


class Student
  include MongoMapper::Document
  many :grades
  key :name, String
end

class Grade
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :grade_score, String
end
```

Ingesting the documents as independent documents instead of embedded documents fixes it..for some reason, the embedding causes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [issue 265](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/265), one of the few I know by number.

To get callbacks to fire on embedded documents in the correct order, MongoMapper has to build a huge stack that grows linearly with the number of embedded docs.  At around ~600-800 docs, the stack overflows.

`ActiveSupport::Callbacks` is a huge mess and would require a rewrite to dodge the issue cleanly (it's less of a mess on Rails head, but still would need rewriting).

The current proposal in issue 265 is to disable the callbacks.

```
# in Gemfile
gem 'mongo_mapper', :git => 'git://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper.git', :ref => 'fefec91027f2dd8eb1ab9caa5a4b0acd000f4da7'
```

And then:

```
class Student
  include MongoMapper::Document
  embedded_callbacks_off
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for identifying this issue. Wasted a whole day getting this to work. I've tried MM 0.8.6 as suggested in the thread but running into other issues. Will probably end up waiting for the abovementioned fix to come in with a newer version. Thanks again